# how to manage the state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing a react application, which shows tasks and projects,but  I don't know how to manage the state

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Components/Header.js'
import Projects from './Components/ProjectsList'
import Task from './Components/Task'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Hours from './Components/Hours'



var projects = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Fifa19",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "1", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "2", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "3", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "4", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "5", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "StarWars",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "5", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "6", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "7", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "8", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "9", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Pocoyo",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "10", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "11", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "12", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "13", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "14", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Doraemon",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "15", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "16", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "17", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "18", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "19", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Lineage 3",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "20", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "21", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "22", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "23", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "24", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  }
]

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    'tasks': [
      { id: "1", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "2", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "3", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "4", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "5", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  }


  handleViewTask = (projectin) => {
  this.setState({
   'tasks':  [{ id: "100", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 }]
  })} 

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header nombre='Joaquin' /> {/*Entregar como name la variable recibida desde server */}
        <Grid container >
          <Grid item xs >
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h5">
              Projects
              </Typography>
            <Projects projects={projects} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs >
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h5">
              Tareas
              </Typography>
            {
              this.state.tasks.map(task =>

                <Task
                  name={task.name}
                  key={task.id}
                  progress={task.progress}
                />
              )
            }

          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h5">
              Configuración
            </Typography>
            <Hours />


          </Grid>
        </Grid>


      </div>
    );

  }

}

export default App;
```

I am implementing a react application, which shows tasks and projects. A project can have many tasks. My main view are all available projects and when clicking on one you should see their corresponding tasks. My question is: With good practices, how should I handle the state of the application? Should the tasks be displayed?

My application for now is like this:

I have an app component with a projects component and other tasks. Each of these has several project and task components respectively.

Comment: Is the UI going to do something display many projects and then click on one project to show tasks.

Comment: See [`Lifting State Up`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Also, [Presentational vs Container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the list of tasks in the state, you should set the selected project id. Have a separate component for the list of tasks, then pass in the list of tasks for the selected project as a prop.

Comment: Thanks very much. i try this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your design. You may show the tasks of a project on the same screen, or you can have a separate page that would do so. Besides, since you do not have a backend service that handles this data, there are not too many options to choose from in regards to how to handle the state.

If you want to show the tasks in the same page, you would have to modify your state to be pretty much like you projects variable:

```
state={
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Fifa19",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "1", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "2", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "3", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "4", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "5", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "StarWars",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "5", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "6", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "7", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "8", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "9", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Pocoyo",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "10", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "11", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "12", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "13", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "14", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Doraemon",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "15", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "16", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "17", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "18", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "19", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Lineage 3",
    'tasks': [
      { id: "20", name: 'diseñar', "progress": 10 },
      { id: "21", name: 'trabajar', "progress": 20 },
      { id: "22", name: 'construir', "progress": 30 },
      { id: "23", name: 'pensar', "progress": 40 },
      { id: "24", name: 'rehacer', "progress": 50 },
    ]
  }
}
```

Or if you want your app to handle it separately, you would need to use the react-router to map the route to your other component and pass on the props to show the data you want. Something like:

```
<Route
  path='/tasks'
  render={(props) => <Tasks{...props}/>}
/>
```

In this case, Tasks would be a functional/dumb component since it will be used only to display data, and it would only be shown when the user clicks on the project or any event you may want to trigger.